# Mixing high-level and low-level interfaces in h5py

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am wondering if there's a way to mix the high-level API with the low-level API using h5py.

Example: I have a hdf5 file I'm accessing through the high-level interface.

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File("Somefile.h5")
ds = f["/path/to/some/Dataset"]
```

Now, the `ds` object is a [h5py.Dataset](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/high/dataset.html#h5py.Dataset) which is perfect for most of what I need to do. However, I'd like to figure out the size of this dataset as stored on disk. The low-level interface provides [h5py.h5d.DatasetID.get_storage_space()](http://h5py.alfven.org/docs-2.0/low/h5d.html#h5py.h5d.DatasetID.get_storage_size) which does exactly what I want, but I don't know how to call this from my high-level object.

Is there a way to find the underlying low-level object from the high-level API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. Although not in the docs, searching through the highlevel object interactively using `dir()` showed the solution. The highlevel objects have links to their corresponding low level objects with non-obvious names.

In the question above, `ds._id` returns the DatasetID associated with the Dataset. Now I can call `ds._id.get_storage_space()`.

Comment: Awesome!  I needed to manipulate the chunk cache, for which I did `dalist = ds._id.get_access_plist()` and `dalist.set_chunk_cache(4096, 8388608, 1.0)`.

Comment: Though that didn't actually work, so I had to follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656421/1194883) instead.