# How to set cache settings while using h5py high level interface?

Tags: python, h5py

I'm trying to increase cache size for my HDF5 files, but it doesn't seem to be working.
This is what I have:

```
import h5py

with h5py.File("test.h5", 'w') as fid:
        # cache settings of file
        cacheSettings = list(fid.id.get_access_plist().get_cache())
        print cacheSettings
        # increase cache
        cacheSettings[2] = int(5 * cacheSettings[2])
        print cacheSettings
        # read cache settings from file
        fid.id.get_access_plist().set_cache(*cacheSettings)
        print fid.id.get_access_plist().get_cache()
```

Here is the output:

```
[0, 521, 1048576, 0.75]
[0, 521, 5242880, 0.75]
(0, 521, 1048576, 0.75)
```

Any idea why reading works, but setting doesn't?
Closing and reopening the file doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using h5py version 2.9.0 or newer, see [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57278604/190597).

---

According to [the docs](http://www.h5py.org/docs/low/h5f.html#h5py.h5f.FileID.get_access_plist), `get_access_plist()` returns a **copy** of the file access property list. So it is not surprising that modifying the copy does not affect the original.

It appears the high-level interface does not provide a way to change the cache settings.

Here is how you could do it using the low-level interface.

```
propfaid = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.FILE_ACCESS)
settings = list(propfaid.get_cache())
print(settings)
# [0, 521, 1048576, 0.75]

settings[2] *= 5
propfaid.set_cache(*settings)
settings = propfaid.get_cache()
print(settings)
# (0, 521, 5242880, 0.75)
```

The above creates a [PropFAID](http://www.h5py.org/docs/low/h5p.html#file-access). We can then open the file and get a [FileID](http://www.h5py.org/docs/low/h5f.html#functional-api) this way:

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(h5py.h5f.open(
                        filename, flags=h5py.h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=propfaid)) as fid:
    # <h5py.h5f.FileID object at 0x9abc694>
    settings = list(fid.get_access_plist().get_cache())
    print(settings)
    # [0, 521, 5242880, 0.75]
```

And we can use the `fid` to open the file with the high-level interface by passing `fid` to `h5py.File`:

```
    f = h5py.File(fid)
    print(f.id.get_access_plist().get_cache())
    # (0, 521, 5242880, 0.75)
```

Thus, you can still use the high-level interface, but it takes some
fiddling to get there. On the other hand, if you distill it to just the essentials, perhaps it isn't so bad:

```
import h5py
import contextlib

filename = '/tmp/foo.hdf5'
propfaid = h5py.h5p.create(h5py.h5p.FILE_ACCESS)
settings = list(propfaid.get_cache())
settings[2] *= 5
propfaid.set_cache(*settings)
with contextlib.closing(h5py.h5f.open(filename, fapl=propfaid)) as fid:
    f = h5py.File(fid)
```

Comment: So after the line:  

`f = h5py.File(fid)`  Can I use the high level API instead to create a data set?:  

`dset = f.create_dataset("zipped_max", (100, 100), compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)`

Comment: Yes; that's the beauty of objects. Once you have the object, it has all the methods of that class, no matter how the object was created.

Comment: Great! I have been using the high-level API but I just realized that I need to take a step back to increase the cache size through the low level API. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am having problems making sure that the file is closed. I have posted a related question: [How to close an HDF5 using low level Python API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988211/how-to-close-an-hdf5-using-low-level-python-api)

Comment: Note that since h5py version 2.9.0, it is possible to manipulate the cache parameters directly through arguments to `h5py.File`.  This answer (+1) is actually what I used to write the code in h5py that does this, but it is no longer necessary for the user to do so.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

As of h5py version 2.9.0, this behavior is now available directly through the main `h5py.File` interface.  There are three parameters that control the "raw data chunk cache" — `rdcc_nbytes`, `rdcc_w0`, and `rdcc_nslots` — which are documented [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#chunk-cache).  The OP was trying to adjust the `rdcc_nbytes` setting, which can now simply be done as

```py
import h5py

with h5py.File("test.h5", "w", rdcc_nbytes=5242880) as f:
    f.create_dataset(...)
```

In this case, I assume that you know how much space you actually need, rather than just multiplying by 5 as the OP wanted.  The current default values are the same as the OP found.  Of course, if you really wanted to do this programatically, you could just open it once, get the cache, close it, and then reopen with the desired parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The [h5py-cache](https://github.com/moble/h5py_cache) project might be helpful, although I haven't used it:

```
import h5py_cache
with h5py_cache.File('test.h5', chunk_cache_mem_size=1024**3, 'a') as f:
    f.create_dataset(...)
```

Comment: Note that this module has been merged into `h5py` itself, so the `h5py_cache` project [of which I am the author] is now deprecated.  See my answer for how to use this.