# How to set different cache sizes for different datasets in h5py?

Tags: python, caching, hdf5, h5py

I am currently working on a ML problem, and I have a h5 file that consists of 2 datasets. One is my training data (a dataset with shape of (length, h, w)), and one is the metadata. That is an np.array of json string of shape (length,).

The problem I have is that h5py.File creates a single cache size for all of the datasets. So although my metadata does not need as much caching as my actual data (it is around 2GB, in comparison to my data which is around 60GB), if I declare a caching mechanism, it will be cached with a similar memory footprint compared to the data that is far more important to cache.

So if I declare a 4GB cache for each dataset, I will cache around 0.17 of my dataset and 100% of my metadata which will consume around 6GB of my memory. Is there any way to use a different cache size for my metadata dataset?

Comment: You didn't post any code to show what you are doing. Are you using this method to set cache size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57278604/10462884. Datasets have a chunk size parameter to control I/O behavior. However, it is set when you create the dataset, so you will have to recreate the .h5 file to try it.

Comment: @kcw78 yes I'm using `rdcc_nslots` and `rdcc_nbytes` parameters for cache size. It is stated that each dataset uses this seperately. Meaning that each one will have a cache size of 4GBs in my case apparently. While I need 4GBs for one and around 200MB for the other.